# Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

I'm making a text crawler using BeautifulSoup. But when I run this code, I get the error code saying that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\Crawling.py", line 33, in <module>
    text = content.get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

I will be very appreciated if you tell me how to fix it.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xml.dom.minidom

keyWord = raw_input("Enter the key-word : ")
#Enter my Search KeyWord

address = "http://openapi.naver.com/search?key=8d4b5b7fef7a607863013302754262a3&query="                   + keyWord + "&display=5&start=1&target=kin&sort=sim"

search_result = urllib.urlopen(address)
raw_data = search_result.read()
parsed_result = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(raw_data)
links = parsed_result.getElementsByTagName('link')

source_URL = links[3].firstChild.nodeValue
#The number 3 has no meaning, it has 0 to 9 and I just chose 3
page = urllib.urlopen(source_URL).read()

#save as html file
g = open(keyWord + '.html', 'w')
g.write(page)
g.close()

#open html file
g = open(keyWord + '.html', 'r')
bs = BeautifulSoup(g)
g.close()


content = bs.find(id="end_content")
text = content.get_text()

#save as text file
h = codecs.open(keyWord + '.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
h.write(keyWord + ' ')
h.write(text)

print "file created"
```

Comment: That error is straightforward: `content` is returning *nothing*, which is why you can't use `get_text` on it.

Answer (score 2):

Taking into consideration both answers of @Hooked and @alecxe, a way to do this using `requests` is as follows. Note that I'll be using the `handbag` keyword for the search query.

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

url = "http://openapi.naver.com/search?key=8d4b5b7fef7a607863013302754262a3&query=handbag&display=100&start=1&target=kin&sort=sim"
result = rq.get(url)
parsed_result = parseString(result.content)
links = parsed_result.getElementsByTagName("link")

new_url = links[3].firstChild.nodeValue
new_result = rq.get(new_url).content

g = open("handbag.html", "w")
g.write(new_result)
g.close()

g = open("handbag.html", "r")
soup = bsoup(g)
g.close()

content = soup.find("div", class_="end_content")
text = content.get_text()

print text.encode("utf-8").strip()
```

The `.encode("utf-8")` part is to handle the output of Korean characters. Result is as follows:

```
아디다스 그래픽핸드백
거의품절이던데............
어디파는데알수없을가요 ㅜ ㅜ ??!?!?
[Finished in 4.7s]
```

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The error clues you into the problem. The offending line comes from:

```
content = bs.find(id="end_content")
```

which is being triggered since your soup, `bs` has no element with an `id="end_content"`. When BeautifulSoup can't find an element, it doesn't raise an error, but simply returns `None`. Look over your source html and double check that the id is the correct one.

As an aside, it may be worth looking into the module [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to handle the url parsing. It is much more robust than simply concatenating the strings like you are doing.

Comment: Yes, `requests` is an awesome library. Totally recommended.

Comment: @user3473222 No problem and welcome to Stack Overflow! You don't have to thank each of us, once you get enough reputation you'll be able to upvote _good_ questions and _good_ answers. You will be able to accept the best answer, please do that - that's how we know the question is resolved!

Comment: @user3473222 also make sure you've accepted answers of previous questions you've asked :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no element with `id="end_content"`, though there is a div with `class="end_content"`.

Replace:

```
content = bs.find(id="end_content")
```

with (note you need to use `class_` here since `class` is a reserved keyword in python):

```
content = bs.find("div", class_="end_content")
```

or, alternatively:

```
content = bs.find("div", {"class": "end_content"})
```

Also, note that for performance and being explicit reasons - better specify the `div` tag here since you know that it's going to be a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

If find_all() can’t find anything, it returns an empty list. If find() can’t find anything, it returns None:

you can find this in [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)

your code equal to None.get_text()